# How detect when finger pass on button and out of button holding finger down on the screen

Tags: android, listener

When I try to drag my finger from one button to other, the first is released, the second is not pressed.
Practically I need the second to be pressed. I thought maybe there was some specific Listener to do this, but I could not find it.

Also, I would need to perform certain operations **at the exact time** that the button is released (banally, the color of the button can be stored in a local variable or in a text view as shown in the sample figure).

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBy1r.jpg)

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [OnTouchEvent-Method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). You could override it and listen for [Motion Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) like ACTION_HOVER_ENTER and ACTION_HOVER_EXIT.